# Insulation for crawl space with framed wall and foundation

Tags: hvac, walls, insulation, basement, heating

[image: crawlspace]

I am encapsulating my crawl space, but not sure what to do with walls above the foundation. At least part of this area could have been a basement I guess, but I am needing to deal with this area due to high humidity level.

I’ve read foam board for the foundation walls is standard, is this the same for walls above the foundation?

Comment: Are those crawl space vents? If they are, adding wall insulation won’t do much good if you don’t infill the vents?

Comment: @LeeSam, yes, those are vents.  Those will be sealed, then foam board insulation with two inch gap from top.

Comment: Hmmm...I’m curious about the 2” gap. Seems like you would not want a gap in the insulation.

Comment: Gap is for termite inspection required by code in some places.